# Laravel/PHP: Unidentified index that does exist

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have an object with a property:

```
protected $recipients = array();
```

In one of my methods I set the contents of the `$recipients` property with an associative array of data using this method:

```
public function setRecipientData($recipientData){
    foreach($recipientData as $key => $value){
        $this->recipients[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

When I dump the contents of `$this->recipients`, the array ends up looking like this:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=6)
      'email'       => string 'info@mycompany.com' (length=29)
      'userEmail'   => string 'xxx@yyy.com' (length=11)
      'first_name'  => string 'Test' (length=4)
      'last_name'   => string 'User' (length=4)
      'jobTitle'    => string 'Customer User' (length=13)
      'phoneNumber' => string '123.456.7890' (length=12)
```

I also have a property that will extract only the email addresses from the property like this:

```
private function getRecipientEmails(){
    $emails = array();
    foreach($this->recipients as $recipient){
        $emailPair = array('email' => $recipient['userEmail']);
        $emails[] =  $emailPair;
    }
    return $emails;
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that when I run the method `getRecipientsEmails()` I get the error:

```
Undefined index: userEmail
```

I don't understand why it's not seeing the index `'userEmail'`. If I dump the nested array it shows a value:

```
private function getRecipientEmails(){
    $emails = array();
    foreach($this->recipients as $recipient){
        dd($emailPair = array('email' => $recipient['userEmail']));
        $emails[] =  $emailPair;
    }
    return $emails;
}
```

Result:

```
array (size=1)
  'email' => string 'xxx@yyy.com' (length=20)
```

I've tried dumping the autoload with composer but it makes no difference.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction??

EDIT: Sorry, I realized that I wrote the wrong method into my original post. I've added the original `getRecipientEmails()` method and the dump that shows the data.

Comment: `$recipient` is your index now and not an array that leads to Undefined index: userEmail it's not a multidimensional array when you transformed it, if you want to access it (your processed array) `this->recipients['userEmail']` should do it

Comment: @DrixsonOseña, I realized I posted the wrong version of the method in my original post. I don't know if that changes anything behind your comment. Also, my hope is that the recipients property would be a multidimensional array as it could possibly hold the data for multiple contacts.

Comment: @John Conde, You marked this post as a duplicate last night. I read through the post that you marked as an answer. I may be missing it, but I don't understand how this solves the issue I'm having. I updated my post last night to include the original version of my method which does include a variable initialization for the `email` array in the `getRecipientEmails()` method and it still does not fix the issue. If you were referring to the recipients property, that property is initialized by default. Am I still missing something here?